# How to create multi product for a specific id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to cosmos db and I am creating a web api project base on cosmos db .I created the basic crud operation. Now the problem one  is vendor has more industry ,in industry vendor may have more than one product .I create one product ,when i try to create more the one ,it show  the error id already used . Here i used the id as partition key . 
Problem two is some vendor may have only category only so i need to add the product directly to them .
please help me to structure it solve the problem .
 Addproduct code:

```
 public async Task<Catalog> AddProduct(
          Catalog order)
        {
            var requestOptions =
                new RequestOptions
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(order.Id.ToString())
                };

            var catalogDocument = await _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                    _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), order, requestOptions);

            return
                (Catalog)((dynamic)catalogDocument.Resource);
        }
```

My json code :

```
    "id": "8000003c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967aa",

    "industy": {

      "category": [
        {

          "subcategory": [
            {
                product1,product2.....
                }
```

error message :
{"code":409,"body":{"code":"Conflict","message":"Entity with the specified id already exists in the system}

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a single giant document for everything like this. Use a separate collection and save each `product` as a separate document with the vendor, industry and category as fields on that document. Then you can modify individual product records easily and retrieve all products for a given vendor or category in a query.

Comment: product update work for a specific vendor .problem is if i enter a new product for a specific vendor old product are replace .

Comment: so i need to do ,without replace add new product

Comment: That's because you're storing everything in a single giant document for a vendor. If you want to do it that way then you'll need to get the entire document first, then make the changes and save the entire document again. This isn't efficient or scalable which is why I recommend using a separate collection of products instead.

Comment: thank you . how to get enter doc and update it . can you please share any code example. thanks in advance